# Create a widget that will display a very long paragraph

Tags: flutter, mobile, widget

I want to create a screen that a very long paragraph.
The widget must be scrollable because it will has a buttom at the end of it.

```
class CloseForm extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              Text("TEXT 1"),
              Text("TEXT 2"),
              Text("TEXT 3"),
              Text("TEXT 4"),
              SizedBox(height: 250.0),
              Center(
                child: ButtonTheme(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () => print("Connect"),
                    elevation: 2.0,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      "Accepter",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    ),
                    color: Color(0xFF5ABA9F),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

}

This will be so exhausting if continue using the TEXT widget to insert every line I just want to know if there is a possbiblity to insert the whole paragraph in one step and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Text widget, you can specify a `maxLines` property.

Like this:

```
            Text(longParagraphTextContent,
                maxLines: 10,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12,
                    color: Color(0xdddddd),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          ],
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using too many Text widgets, you can just use one text widget and break lines using '\n'.

The best approach is to use maxlines property as Didier said